# signalr/reconnect takes too long

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr-hub

I have an application running on azure cloud, currently on a single node. The application it's working properly but looking the logs I can see that some times signalr operations like connect or reconnect takes very large times:

**Request**  --                **Time (ms)**

GET /signalr/reconnect--26,132,725.3971
GET /signalr/connect--6,845,497.6311
GET /signalr/connect--6,037,805.5604
GET /signalr/connect--4,892,617.2957
GET /signalr/reconnect--3,432,113.4963
GET /signalr/reconnect--3,222,554.4094
GET /signalr/reconnect--3,154,466.1479
GET /signalr/reconnect--3,120,839.3401
GET /signalr/reconnect--3,115,460.5552
GET /signalr/reconnect--2,170,759.2398
...

I dont find this times to be normal so I figure I might be doing something wrong. 
I'm Using a hub to stablish the signalr and I do not overwrite any of the Hub class methods.
Looking carefully at the logs I can see that all the time consumming request are comming for a very small subset of clients, only five of about two hundred.

In the client Side I manage the connection end reconection with this code:

```
    var hub = $.connection.hub,
        serverEventsHub = $.connection.serverEventsHub,
        server = serverEventsHub.server,
        client = serverEventsHub.client;

    hub.disconnected(function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () { 
            hub.start();
        }, 5000);
    });
   hub.start();
```

Can anyone tell why sometimes those request take so long?

Comment: Define what you mean by normal. Where is your code that reconnects or connects? If you narrow your problem down, you would receive more help.

Comment: I have added the client code, in the server side there is no connection reconection code more than the one in the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub class